# spring @modelattribute polymorphism

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have two concrete classes, Person1 and Person2 extending Person. I want a spring jsp form to create a Person1 or a Person2.

```
public abstract class Person{


}


public class Person1 extends Person{

}

public class Person2 extends Person{

}
```

I have some field in html form describing the class type (Person1 or Person2).  How can I automatically create a Person by using the @ModelAttribute annotation?

```
public String create(@ModelAttribute Person person){

   // person here can be instance of Person1 or Person2
   ...
}
```

Comment: You could have two method in controller - one with `Person1` and second with `Person2` as a `@ModelAttribute` - and just invoke shared method `controllerStuff(Person person)`. It's just a workaround, I'm sure there's a better solution

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300586/modelattribute-and-abstract-class) could help