# @ModelAttribute with an abstract class in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am trying to submit form data from a JSP to a controller and have the data bind to one of two implementations of an abstract class based on a "type" field in the form. I saw this post that sounded promising, but after creating and registering a converter, it is not being called: [@ModelAttribute and abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300586/modelattribute-and-abstract-class)

What am I missing? The wiring looks correct to me, but this is also my first time trying to configure this.

When I submit the form data, my controller throws this exception: `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.project.types.Food]: Is it an abstract class?`

Here is the abstract class structure:

```
abstract Food
String type

Banana extends Food
Apple extends Food
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/web/pickFood", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView foodSubmit(@ModelAttribute("food") Food food) {...}
```

My converter:

```
public class FoodConverter implements Converter<String, Food> {

    @Override
    public Food convert(String type) {
        Food food = null;
        switch (type) {
            case "banana":
                food = new Banana();
                break;
            case "apple":
                food = new Apple();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown food type:" + type);
        }
        return food;
    }
}
```

How I register the converter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class FoodWebMvCContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new FoodConverter());
    }
}
```

And the form on my JSP, right now I just want to submit the type and see it convert to an empty food object of that type.

```
<form:form method="POST"
                   action="/web/pickFood"
                   modelAttribute="food">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="type">Type</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="type" name="food"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
 </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing the input of my form from

```
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="type">Type</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="type" name="food"/></td>
</tr>
```

to

```
<tr>
    <input type="text" name="food" />
</tr>
```